# Error when trying to run Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following docker file which runs a spring beans application and also selenium

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15

# Google Chrome

ARG CHROME_VERSION=87.0.4280.88-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

## ChromeDriver

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=87.0.4280.88
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

With google-chrome.repo:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

my pom.xml has:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am trying to use chrome like this in Java:

```
try {
            LOGGER.error("About to set up ChromeDriver");
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            LOGGER.error("About to create ChromeDriver");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
            LOGGER.error("About to wait 5 seconds");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("I got an error", e);
        }
```

and I am getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '4271739d398f', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.39-linuxkit', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5616fb303e79 <unknown>

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543) ~[na:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar!/:na]
    at com.example.flockta.FlocktaApplication.hello(FlocktaApplication.java:35) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
...
```

Does anyone know how to fix it so that it runs successfully?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not setting the correct Chrome options. I needed to set:

```
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
            List<String> arguments = new LinkedList<>();
            arguments.add("--disable-extensions");
            arguments.add("--headless");
            arguments.add("--disable-gpu");
            arguments.add("--no-sandbox");

            arguments.add("--no-sandbox");
            arguments.add("--incognito");
            arguments.add("--disable-application-cache");
            arguments.add("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```